# Terraform: Iterating a resources over multiple values?

Tags: terraform

I'm testing the PAN-OS provider from Palo Alto networks, with the goal of configuring a firewall as-code. I can easily make a security policy:

```
resource "panos_security_policy" "security_policy" {
    rule {
        name = var.name
        source_zones = var.source_zones
        source_addresses = var.source_addresses
        source_users = var.source_users
        destination_zones = var.destination_zones
        destination_addresses = var.destination_addresses
        applications = var.applications
        services = var.services
        categories = var.categories
        action = var.action
    }
}
```

I have 50+ rules that will need to be managed this way. I could brute-force each rule as an individual resource, or I could use a module with mapped values. But both of those seem like a lot of manual work and hard to maintain. Any ideas for the most efficient way to iterate this resource over a set of values? Anyone who has had to manage a large AWS security group with lots of rules may know of something.

Comment: Well, you could use a `for_each` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for_each` loop, e.g.

```
for_each = { for k, v in var.rules : k => v }

name = each.key
source_zones = each.value.source_zones
source_addresses = each.value.source_addresses
source_users = each.value.source_users
...
```

on variables file:

```
rules = {
    rulename1 = {
      source_zones   = "foo"
      source_address = "bar"
      source_users   = "baz"
    }
    rulename2 = {
      source_zones   = "foo"
      source_address = "biz"
      source_users   = "buz"
    }
  }
```

Make sure to read [this](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) if you need further details.